# ssh - execute complex remote command

Tags: ssh, logs, remote

I want to execute the following **shell** command on a **remote** machine:

```
/bin/retail -f -u 'INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

This command uses a binary called `retail`, which basically is a normal Linux `tail` with some extra sugar. For more information you can check out **[this](https://github.com/mwh/retail)** github repo.

When I input the command above inside a shell **on the remote machine** itself, it does what I want, so the command as it is written is correct from the functional perspective. It does what I want.

Problem is I want to **execute** that command within a script **on my laptop** and trigger the remote machine.

This is what **I tried**, but all commands do not print the desired output, instead they **print no log line** at all:

```
ssh sshuser@my-server.net.bar /bin/retail -f -u "INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]" /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

Then I tried escaping `[` and `]` or using `'` instead of `"` and probably every combination of it, but everything **didn't work**.

The **desired output** is: Behave like a normal `tail` and then exit if the new line matches the specified one in the string. *Again, when I execute it on the remote machine it works as described.*

I was asking myself: Maybe `retail` can't function over ssh? I have tried the normal Unix `tail` and **it works** over ssh. The Author of `retail` says its **POSIX compliant** and one can replace his system `tail` with it. So, I guess it is also **not a problem** of the binary itself.

So the problem really is: How can I format the argument of the `ssh` command, so that it picks up the command correctly?

---

### Response to comment of **Jaken551**:

If you mean:

```
ssh sshuser@my-server.net.bar '/bin/retail -f -u "INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]" /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out'
```

Then, yes I have tried that already. It also prints **no log line** and does not return to the input prompt.

---

### Response to answer of **Gerard H. Pille**:

Unfortunately the **same behaviour**. Does not print log and does not return to input prompt. For completeness, I tried this:

```
ssh sshuser@my-server.net.bar /bin/retail -f -u \'INFORMATION \\[main\\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \\[\\\"ajp-nio-8009\\\"\\]\' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

---

### Response to answer of **Patrick**:

Unfortunately, also a negative. For completeness, I tried both of the suggested solutions. Here the **first one**:

```
CMD="$(printf "%q " /bin/retail -f -u 'INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out)"
ssh sshuser@my-server.net.bar "$CMD"
```

**Result:** Does not print log and does not return to input prompt.

And the **second one**:

```
ssh -T sshuser@my-server.net.bar <<'EOF'
/bin/retail -f -u 'INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
EOF
```

**Result:** Outputs a Pseudo-Terminal, but **not the log** and does **not** return to the **input prompt**:

```
 Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Linux my-remote-server 4.1.15-1-lts #1 SMP Tue Dec 15 20:54:13 CET 2015 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
```

---

Since I **tried out** a couple of solutions now, I should try out **invoking a sh-script**, which contains the `retail` command as **Gerard H. Pille** suggested. I still would like to have **nice one-liner** when possible (without writing a script that contains the line).

---

### Response to **Archemar** answer:

I took the original command, which I specified and added a `-t` to it, resulting in the following:

```
ssh -t sshuser@my-server.net.bar /bin/retail -f -u "INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]" /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

and **it worked**. Archemar you should write your **comment as an answer** so i can checkmark it.

Comment: Have you wrapped the remote command `/bin/retail -f -u "INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]" /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out` in single quotes? Such as `sshuser@my-server.net.bar 'command args' `.

Comment: I suspect something you're telling us is incorrect. There is no reason why some of these would work locally and not remote unless details are being left out. In one of your responses, the output even indicates that the command you ran is not the command you say you ran (the one about `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated ...`).

Comment: @Patrick: I can understand you are being pissed, but I did not exclude any crucial information.

Comment: What makes you think I'm pissed? I'm not. I'm simply stating that we cannot help you without accurate, complete, information.

Comment: It is what it is, I provided every bit of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometime commands deal with terminals, since this is not a `$PATH` issue, you might whish for `ssh` to allocate a `tty`.

as per `man ssh`

> -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very use‐
>                ful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

simply use

```
ssh -t sshuser@host ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Jaken551's recommendation is close to the actual solution, but is slightly off due to the extra level of nested quotation. Lets take a look at what's going on with this first.

My usual technique for this is to just throw an `echo` on the front of the command (it's not perfect, but it's usually good enough).

```
# Your original command which you say works locally
$ echo 'INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\] /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out

# The command though ssh
$ ssh example.com echo "INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]" /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
INFORMATION [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009] /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out

# The command through ssh with the quotes
$ ssh example.com 'echo "INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]" /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out'
INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \["ajp-nio-8009"\] /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

So notice the difference in the outputs. In both of the `ssh` versions, the escaping is different.

What's going on in the first `ssh` example is that the first level of quotation is getting stripped by the local shell, then `ssh` is receiving multiple arguments (`echo`, `INFORMATION \[main\] ...`), which it then concatenates together into a single argument `echo INFORMATION \[main\] ...`, which then gets evaluated through the shell on the remote side as `sh -c 'echo INFORMATION \[main\] ...'`.

In the second `ssh` example, again the first level of quoting gets stripped by the local shell so ssh receives `echo "INFORMATION \[main\] ..."`, which then gets evaluated on the remote side as `sh -c 'echo "INFORMATION \[main\] ..."'`. So it's a little better, but you're still dealing with 2 levels of shells stripping your quotations & escapes.

There are 2 ways you can approach this. The first is to instead pass your command on STDIN, which will ensure your command is only getting processed by a shell once, at the actual execution time:

```
ssh -T example.com <<'EOF'
echo 'INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
EOF
INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\] /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

However this means that the remote command does not have access to your TTY or STDIN, so if the command needs STDIN, it won't work.

The second approach is to have the shell add an extra level of quotation for you.

```
$ CMD="$(printf "%q " echo 'INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out)"
$ ssh example.com "$CMD"
INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\] /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

<sup>*(you don't need the intermediary `$CMD`, and you could do an inline `ssh ... "$(printf "%q " ...)"`, I just did it separately for legibility)*</sup>

TL;DR: Either of the following will work for you:

```
ssh -T sshuser@my-server.net.bar <<'EOF'
/bin/retail -f -u 'INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
EOF

CMD="$(printf "%q " /bin/retail -f -u 'INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out)"
ssh sshuser@my-server.net.bar "$CMD"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your job would have been much easier if you'd just created a script on the other system that did what you wanted, and then called that script without any parameters.   An alternative is creating a script on the other side, that shows you what parameters it receives, something like echo_args.sh:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "$0 $@"
ARG=1
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  echo "$ARG: $1"
  shift
  (( ARG++ ))
done
```

Then you can call:

```
ssh tomcat@rmgdmzwebapp02.dmz.local bin/echo_args.sh  -f -u \'INFORMATION \\[main\\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \\[\\\"ajp-nio-8009\\\"\\]\' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

and you get:

```
bin/echo_args.sh -f -u INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\] /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
1: -f
2: -u
3: INFORMATION \[main\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \[\"ajp-nio-8009\"\]
4: /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

which shows you that the parameters arrive correctly on the other side.
Now you just replace echo_args.sh by your retail programme:

```
ssh sshuser@my-server.net.bar /bin/retail -f -u \'INFORMATION \\[main\\] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler \\[\\\"ajp-nio-8009\\\"\\]\' /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```